# Get current session info using separate linked php file

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, echo

These are the only times Select shows up in the file. . . .

```
function GetUserFromEmail($email,&$user_rec)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }   
    $email = $this->SanitizeForSQL($email);

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from $this->tablename where email='$email'",$this->connection);  

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("There is no user with email: $email");
        return false;
    }
    $user_rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    return true;
}
```

and . . .

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);

$nresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->tablename WHERE username = '$username'", $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($nresult);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $nresult = mysql_fetch_array($nresult);
        $salt = $nresult['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $nresult['password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);


    }


    $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$hash' and confirmcode='y'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['phone_of_user'] = isset($row['phone'])?$row['phone']:'phone not set';


    return true;
}
```

Also, this is the only time $row shows up as well. The functions being called from the other php file is as follows . . . .

```
<p id="mobilecheck" align="center"> Willkommen z&uuml;ruck <? echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>! </br>
```

Willkommen UserPhone(); ?>! 
 Willkommen züruck UserEmail(); ?>!

Comment: Are you sure that $row['phone'] is set ? If you get an Undefined index notice for $row['phone'] your $_SESSION variable will not be set and will always write an empty string. You can do this: $_SESSION['phone_of_user']  = isset($row['phone'])?$row['phone']:'phone not set'; and see if it actualy works.

Comment: Have you used to the session_start() function at the top of the page? If you have not used that then you will be not able to access the values of the session through out the page and through out the website too. Please, Check the session in w3cshool.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia I'm pretty sure he used it. He complains that only the phone number is not working, the rest of $_SESSION variables do work.

Comment: Is `$row['phone']` the correct column name selected from the database

Comment: I tried     $_SESSION['phone_of_user'] = isset($row['phone'])?$row['phone']:'phone not set';               no change. Where the UserName and UserEmail show up the UserPhone is still blank. If they all three are written the exact same, in theory, if one is set, shouldn't they all be set?

Comment: @Rick a variable will be set only if in your code is explicitely defined/declared. Coming back to help you: so we do have a value coming from database. Are you sure is not empty? Check like this: $_SESSION['phone_of_user']  = (strlen(trim($row['phone']))>0)?$row['phone']:'i received an empty value from my query';

Comment: @besciualex: Then i think Rick must put the database table structure also so that we can come know if there is any issue of the database table field

Comment: id_user int(11) No     
name varchar(128) No     
email varchar(64) No     
phone varchar(64) No     
Addressline1 varchar(64) No     
Addressline2 varchar(64) No     
Stadt varchar(64) No     
username varchar(16) No     
salt varchar(50) No     
password varchar(80) No     
confirmcode varchar(32) Yes  NULL

Comment: Correction to besciualex . . now ----"phone is not set" does appear.

Comment: So I guess my follow up question is, how do I set it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, phone is the name of the column. I assume $row['phone'] is referring to that column. It's the same thing that is written for name and email and both are working.

Comment: @Rick Update the question and add in the code block the lines where $row first appear. If you also see a query (e.g. "SELECT * FROM...") put that too. We need these information in order to help you.

Comment: Show us the query just to make sure

Comment: Not sure how to edit question : This is the first time $ row shows up $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        
        
        $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['phone_of_user'] = isset($row['phone'])? $row['phone']:'phone not set';

Comment: function GetUserFromEmail($email,&$user_rec)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }   
        $email = $this->SanitizeForSQL($email);
        
        $result = mysql_query("Select * from $this->tablename where email='$email'",$this->connection);  

        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $this->HandleError("There is no user with email: $email");
            return false;
        }
        $user_rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        
        return true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick, 
I'll wite here so you will understand better. For debugging purposes do the next thing:

1. instead of `$_SESSION['phone_of_user']  = $row['phone'];` put this: `$_SESSION['phone_of_user']  = $row; //This will put an entire array in your variable`
2. instead of:

`<p id="mobilechiiieckby" align="center"> Willkommen <? echo $fgmembersite->UserPhone(); ?>! </br>`

write this:

```
<p id="mobilechiiieckby" align="center"><pre><?php print_r($_SESSION['phone_of_user']); ?>!</pre></p>
```

These two simple modifications will help you see what's inside $row variable. After you see it's content you can play with it. Let's continue the discussion here, and I'll update this answer with new information.

Later edit:
Update this line:

```
$qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$hash' and confirmcode='y'";
```

with this one:

```
$qry = "Select name, email, phone from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$hash' and confirmcode='y'";
```

Comment: I replaced the two lines you suggested. A progress of a sort. Now instead of simply being blank its returning  "Array!"

Comment: @Rick I updated the last line of code. Replace it again. What's the output now ?

Comment: This is the output of the updated line     ........  Array [name] => testname [email =>richard.t.rohrig@gmail.com])!     ......I see phone is not included in the array. What can I do to include it?

Comment: @Rick Let me know if the last line brings you phone in the array you work with it. If it did, then return to your previous code (before you asked on stackoverflow), and update only the $qry variable as in my answer. That will do the trick you wanted. :)